# Metro App Identify All Emoticons from Segoe UI Symbol

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, emoticons

Is there a way of listing ALL emoticons from the **Segoe UI Symbol** font?

I can get all the symbols no problem, but how do I identify which of these are emoticons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, there is no direct way to do that.
With a little bit of googling I came up with:

emoticons => Segoe UI Symbol (87)

emoticon: 2639-263b, 2661, 2665, 2764, 1f48b, 1f48f-1f49f, 1f600-1f64f (you can just check unicode ranges to verify if it's emoticon or not)

☹☺☻ ♡ ♥ ❤

You are probably better off using charmap + doing manual labour work and hardcode them into your application, since it's not that much of work anyways.

Sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:ChristTrekker/UnicodeSymbol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji

Answer (score 1):

There's one awasome app called [Xaml Candy](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/xaml-candy/8b9e2d69-feed-409c-befb-4ea97f97351a), just have a look. Must have app for developer. It is helpful to choose appbar icons.
DISCLAIMER : I am not the developer of this app nor I am promoting it.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows8, standart app "symbol table"